# Managing stolen iPad via Profile Manager

Tags: ios, ipad, security, mobile-device-management, profile-manager

We have deployed 50 iPads in field managed via Profile Manager. Recently one of the iPads got stolen. Unfortunately Find my iPad was turned off on it. We tried to wipe the iPad using Profile Manager but no success which made me think that probably stolen iPad needs to be connected to internet then it will be wiped. Is there anything we can do to save our data. Moving forward in future what could be the best and cost effective way to deal with lost or stolen iPads and protecting our data without spending alot or moving away from Profile Manager to other Mobile Device Management (MDM) solution. I have already instructed all iPad users to keep Find my iPad app on which again poses the limitation that lost or stolen iPad has to be connected to internet in order for it to be wiped.

Answer (score 1):

In profile manager you could set/force a passcode option under settings that could wipe the device after so many failed attempts which does not require internet access.